# Linq query fetches different value than sql query view

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I have created a **view** in SQL server by joining 3 tables and using Entity Framework and accessing it in my application.

I have the following code to get the value from view table.

```
 tapDataContext.TapTimeSheetViews.
Where(timesheet=>timesheet.UserId==userId && timesheet.WorkDate==dates);
```

this fetches duplicate values. But, sql query gives proper values.

I had referred [this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217285/linq-select-on-a-sql-view-gets-wrong-answer)  and added

```
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public long TapStartStopDataId { get; set; }
```

as key value.
But still, I don't get proper result when I execute my application.

Comment: You should post SQL query as well, so that both can be compared.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found the solution
I used  `row_number() over (order by Id) as rownum,` to create a new column and gave that as key.I deleted my EDMX diagram and added again so new column will populate there and i got the desired result