# Identity mapping to a view with Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

It's a common enough problem: you have a view that contains no primary key identifier, or even any combination of columns that guarantees each row to be unique. And you want to use this view in Entity Framework. What do you do?

It's been [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11371825/6680521) that you modify the view to add a generated primary key, for instance:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER(ORDER BY Activity) AS ID, * FROM MyView
```

However, because `Activity` is not unique, the generated identifier can and will change each time you query the view.

Consider the following scenario where you have the view:

```
Activity   CustomerName  Cost
Skiing     John          81.50
Skydiving  Sarah         199.99
Skydiving  Robert        215.00
```

and you add an `ID` column over `Activity`:

```
ID  Activity   CustomerName  Cost
1   Skiing     John          81.50
2   Skydiving  Sarah         199.99
3   Skydiving  Robert        215.00
```

Now suppose a user requests this view on a webpage.

Shortly afterwards, someone else adds a booking for snowboarding, causing the view to become:

```
ID  Activity      CustomerName  Cost
1   Snowboarding  Michael       85.00
2   Skiing        John          81.50
3   Skydiving     Sarah         199.99
4   Skydiving     Robert        215.00
```

The first user wants to see more details about Sarah's skydiving booking, so he selects that row from the page and sends a new request with `ID = 2`. But the backing view has changed since he loaded the page, and now `ID = 2` refers to John's skiing booking, causing the wrong info to be loaded.

The moral of the story: `row_number()` doesn't reliably uniquely identify each row in a view.

(Now, arguably this is a misuse of views, and it should be pointing at a table directly, but there could be any number of reasons to use a view, such as unioning the data from multiple sources).

Is there any solution or workaround for this issue?

Comment: Have you considered adding multiple keys to the view, such as Activity.Id as ActivityId and Customer.Id as CustomerId and then using those id's to navigate to the ActivityDetail and CustomerDetail respectively?

Comment: @Kris I think I'm going to have to implement a solution like that, yeah. I was hoping MVC had some way of programmatically adding a unique identifier, but short of making every column a primary key (which isn't possible with some of the data types) it doesn't seem like it.