# Recuperating tree structure in SQL without content duplication

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a tree structure that I am trying to recuperate via a statement in sql developer for an output display. The tree is of four levels, while level four represents the documents attached on level three.

this is my query:

```
select CASE WHEN level=4 THEN node.name  END as Level_One,
       CASE WHEN level=5 THEN node.name  END as Level_Two,
       CASE WHEN level=6 THEN node.name  END as Level_Three,
       doc.lib_doc as LABEL

  from treenode node

  left join rules ru on ru.datatype = node.octype

  left join prs pr on pr.key = ru.datatype

  left join file fl on fl.code = pr.prcode

  left join ref_doc refd on refd.mn_doc = fl.code
 
  left join ref_document doc on refd.id_doc = doc.id_doc

  connect by prior node.key = node.father_id

  start with node.father_id =-1;
```

The problem is that I am displaying the same level three node.name for each doc.lib_doc attached and thus getting the same value duplicated as much as there are doc.lib_doc as below:

| Level_One | Level_Two | Level_Three | LABEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 - resp | 1 - Right | 1 - Element | abc |
|  |  | 1 - Element | test |
|  |  | 1 - Element | 125 |
|  |  | 1 - Element | test1 |
|  |  | 1 - Element | file |
|  |  | 2 - ElementA | fileXYZ |
|  |  | 2 - ElementA | fileABC |
| 2 - respa | 1 - Access | 1 - right | abc |

While I am without success trying to get the display below without duplication in tree levels:

| Level_One | Level_Two | Level_Three | LABEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 - resp | 1 - Right | 1 - Element | abc |
|  |  |  | test |
|  |  |  | 125 |
|  |  |  | test1 |
|  |  |  | file |
|  |  | 2 - ElementA | fileXYZ |
|  |  |  | fileABC |
| 2 - respa | 1 - Access | 1 - right | abc |

Any suggestions on how to achieve this behavior in the statement?

Answer (score 0):

You could use lag to see the prev value and compare. I know the  below syntax for lag works in SQL Server. Not sure about oracle though.

```
select CASE WHEN level=4 THEN node.name  END as Level_One,
       CASE WHEN level=5 THEN node.name  END as Level_Two,
   CASE WHEN level=6 THEN  decode ( lag(node.name, 1) over( order by null), node.name, '', node_name) END as Level_Three,
        doc.lib_doc as LABEL

  from treenode node

  left join rules ru on ru.datatype = node.octype

  left join prs pr on pr.key = ru.datatype

  left join file fl on fl.code = pr.prcode

  left join ref_doc refd on refd.mn_doc = fl.code
 
  left join ref_document doc on refd.id_doc = doc.id_doc

  connect by prior node.key = node.father_id

  start with node.father_id =-1;
```

Comment: I am getting missing from on select 1... what are you trying to do with the select 1 ?

Comment: order by is a required field.. and i don't see any ordering for your data. The select 1 is to circumvent that. Similar to :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44105691/row-number-without-order-by