# How do I turn Rows to fixed Columns in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, transpose

Hi help me with the below query:
My current data table are as follow.

| flight_id | route |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | BAHRAIN |
| 2 | VIENNA |
| 2 | DUBAI |
| 3 | DUBAI |
| 3 | COCHIN |
| 3 | DOHA |
| 3 | COLOMBO |
| 4 | LONDON |
| 4 | MOSCOW |
| 4 | CHENNAI |
| 4 | DELHI |
| 4 | VNUKOVO |
| 4 | DUBAI |

I want transpose my data table into below format. I think it is something like Pivot, but can't figure out how to do it. :)

| flight_id | route1 | route2 | route3 | route4 | route5 | route6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BAHRAIN | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| 2 | VIENNA | DUBAI | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| 3 | DUBAI | COCHIN | DOHA | COLOMBO | N/A | N/A |
| 4 | LONDON | MOSCOW | CHENNAI | DELHI | VNUKOVO | DUBAI |

Please help me!

Thank!

Comment: What's your logic to determin which city belongs to route N?

Comment: N/A in some routes means that there is no data for that route, for an example flight_id 1 there is only one route and it is to select as route1 and flight_id 4 there are 6 routes in that id which will select in entire 6 routes. I want select upto 6 routes.

Comment: That doesn't address the question - eg why is DELHI `route4` and not any other? Note - "because that's how I have listed it on screen" is not applicable.

Comment: Rows in a table have no defined order. Without any logic based on columns within the table, it is IMPOSSIBLE to know that flight 4 "starts" with London and continues on to Moscow then Chennai etc. in that specific order. Maybe that is not important and you don't care how "routes" are ordered for any flight. That idea is generally very rare.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this is typically to use an `aggregated conditional case expression`.

I have ordered the cities alphabetically to determine the route 1-6; if you have a different requirement, amend the `order by` criteria of the `row_number` function to use the relevant column or expression.

```
with r as (
    select *, Row_Number() over(partition by flight_id order by route) rn
    from flights
)
select 
    flight_id,
        Max(case when rn = 1 then route end) Route1,
        Max(case when rn = 2 then route end) Route2,
        Max(case when rn = 3 then route end) Route3,
        Max(case when rn = 4 then route end) Route4,
        Max(case when rn = 5 then route end) Route5,
        Max(case when rn = 6 then route end) Route6
from r
group by flight_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a pivot alternative.

There's no need to worry about the **order by (select null)** clause [read about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44106422/9925593) but you have to set some field in order to keep the sequence.

```
select * from
(
  select
    [flight_id], 
    [route],
    concat('route',
      (row_number() over (partition by [flight_id] order by (select null)))
    ) [routeId]
  from [routes]
) t  
pivot  
(  
  max([route]) 
  for [routeId] in ([route1], [route2], [route3], [route4], [route5], [route6])  
) p 


-- result
/**
 * +-----------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+--------+
 * | flight_id | route1  | route2 | route3  | route4  | route5  | route6 |
 * +-----------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+--------+
 * |         1 | BAHRAIN | NULL   | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL   |
 * |         2 | VIENNA  | DUBAI  | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL   |
 * |         3 | DUBAI   | COCHIN | DOHA    | COLOMBO | NULL    | NULL   |
 * |         4 | LONDON  | MOSCOW | CHENNAI | DELHI   | VNUKOVO | DUBAI  |
 * +-----------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+--------+
 */
```