# SQL: Merge two result set without any conditions

Tags: sql, t-sql, merge

I have two tables like this:

`Table1` with column `N`

```
N
---
1
2
3
4
5
```

And `Table2` with column `M`:

```
M
---
5
9
1
8
1
```

Finally, I want to combine these two data sets with the same count of rows and also, save source order like this result:

```
N  M
------
1  5
2  9
3  1
4  8
5  1
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Row by row? Preserving order? Tables would have to be the same length and it's a very non-DB thing to do...

Comment: @AER I agree with you, But I need this result set.

Comment: Based on your update (which BTW invalidates my earlier answer below), you _can't_ achieve what you want, because your tables are lacking a second column which maintains the ordering you perceive.  Keep in mind that SQL tables are modeled after sets; they have no internal order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Tim's answer. Also, this [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44106422/3526038) I could achieve my requirement and save source tables orders.

Like this:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT n, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
    FROM @TempTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT m, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
    FROM @TempTable2
)

SELECT t1.n, t2.m
FROM cte1 t1
INNER JOIN cte2 t2
    ON t2.rn = t1.rn
ORDER BY t1.rn
```

**Point**:

> There is no need to worry about specifying constant in the ORDER BY
> expression.

**Sources**:

[ROW_NUMBER Without ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44105691/3526038)

[Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74127250/3526038)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to *view* this output we can use a `ROW_NUMBER()` trick here:

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT N, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N) rn
    FROM Table1
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT M, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY M DESC) rn
    FROM Table2
)

SELECT t1.N, t2.M
FROM cte1 t1
INNER JOIN cte2 t2
    ON t2.rn = t1.rn
ORDER BY t1.rn;
```

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` should also work for tsql as per tag as well.

Comment: And use `OUTER JOIN` if the tables aren't of equal length

Comment: @AER I have no idea why I thought I saw the MySQL tag.  Regarding the left join, I will wait for the OP to also leave a comment about uneven tables.

Comment: @AER - then you will need a `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I wanna save records orders in the source table

Comment: Then use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, where the select is the query in my answer above.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please look at my new data examples.